# Apache Redirect based on WordPress permissions

Tags: mysql, user-roles, apache

On our company website, we have two different types of download permissions: One for legacy, one for current.  Is there a way for me to code a redirect through Apache that will query MySQL for the current user's permissions and redirect them to the correct download URL automatically?

To be a bit more specific, the User Roles in WordPress are 'general_dl' and 'legacy_dl'.  I want to be able to direct the user to respective download pages based on which role they have assigned to them.

The downloads are stored in the /siteroot/public-html/upload/files/ in which there are several download directories based on the version of the software. They are accessed through the Folder Manager WP module.

**Turns out this is unrelated to wordpress**

I was finally brought up to speed on what needs to actually happen, which is totally out of the WordPress scope.  We need to redirect in apache based on a 401 code and a non-null username in the credentials.  The company that designed the new site left our legacy code in place for this task, so we can't do it with PHP or with WordPress until we rebuild everything.  We are looking for a temporary patch until we are ready.

Comment: " Is there a way for me to code a redirect into .htaccess that will query MySQL..." -- No. `.htaccess` is not capable of that kind of scripting. It will have to be handled through PHP and WordPress. There isn't really enough detail to answer the question though.

Comment: Understandable.  I apologize for the lack of detail.  Is there any info I can give that would allow you to visualize the situation more clearly?

Comment: Well, how are your downloads handled for one? Where are they stored? How are they accessed? Etc. Why do you think you need `.htaccess` for this?

Comment: The downloads are stored in the /siteroot/public-html/upload/files/ in which there are several download directories based on the version of the software.  They are accessed through the Folder Manager WP module.  I was thinking .htaccess for mod_rewrite usage, but I am more just looking for any way to do this within apache.

Comment: Please edit that into the question, but you won't be able to query the database within Apache. You will need PHP for that.

Comment: What about using mod_authn_dbd?  We already have multiple queries in place in our current configuration that perform a MySQL query to determine authentication.

Comment: That's interesting. I wasn't aware of that extension, but if have it available it might work but you'd need to be able to match WordPress' hashing algorithms.

Comment: It isn't a problem querying for the correct criteria, but I don't know how to do a conditional redirect based on this criteria.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is likely best done in a simple WordPress plugin.

You're user roles are already stored in WordPress, so a plugin to do this is likely only a few lines long.

Also an existing plugin like [File Away](https://wordpress.org/plugins/file-away/) may accomplish what your attempting. This plugin surfaced when I did a plugin search for the terms...

```
download directory based on wordpress user role
```